# Define variable and echo in function

Tags: php, echo

I'm creating a WordPress plugin to bring in fields from a XenForo forum and display them in WordPress.

I have a file called xf_connector.php which has the following code:

```
<?php

$startTime = microtime(true);
$fileDir = 'C:\Domains\xxxx.com\httpdocs\forums';

require($fileDir . '/library/XenForo/Autoloader.php');
XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader($fileDir . '/library');

XenForo_Application::initialize($fileDir . '/library', $fileDir);
XenForo_Application::set('page_start_time', $startTime);

XenForo_Session::startPublicSession();

$visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance()->toArray();
?>
```

And then a separate file called xf.php which has the following code:

```
<body>
<p>Hello <?php $xf_userId = $visitor['user_id'];
$xf_username = $visitor['username'];
echo "$xf_username" ?> welcome to this web page.</p>

<p>Hello <?php $xf_userId = $visitor['user_id'];
$xf_username = $visitor['username'];
echo "$xf_username" ?> welcome to this web page.</p>

</body>
```

This works fine in a blank document but does not work in the WordPress plugin. My plugin file is currently:

```
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/xf_connector.php' );

function xenfield_shortcode() {
  ob_start(); ?> 
  <div class="xenfield">
<?php $xf_userId = $visitor['user_id'];
$xf_username = $visitor['username'];
echo "$xf_username" ?>
  </div>
  <?php    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'xenfield', 'xenfield_shortcode' );
```

This displays nothing on the WordPress page and if I look at the HTML it just shows empty `<p>` tags.

How can I define a variable and echo it in the same file so it displays in WordPress?

Comment: Please do not abuse the code snippet tool. It is for HTML/CSS/JS *only*.

Comment: Sorry, I could not see a way to input PHP as a block and not plain text. My apologies

Answer (score 2):

`$visitor` is not defined in your function xenfield_shortcode(). I guess that this will work:

```php
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/xf_connector.php' );

function xenfield_shortcode() {
  $visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance()->toArray();

  ob_start(); ?> 
  <div class="xenfield">
<?php $xf_userId = $visitor['user_id'];
$xf_username = $visitor['username'];
echo "$xf_username" ?>
  </div>
  <?php    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'xenfield', 'xenfield_shortcode' );
```

And while we are at it, this makes it much more readable:

```php
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/xf_connector.php' );

function xenfield_shortcode() {
    $visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance()->toArray();

    $output = '<div class="xenfield">';
    $output .= $visitor['username'];
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'xenfield', 'xenfield_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Ah, I didnt realise you needed to define the varible also, I thought my $xf_userId = $visitor was doing that.

It works anyway, Thanks for your help!

Comment: That defines `$xf_userId`, based on the content of `$visitor`, but as `$visitor` was undefined, it didn't really do anything.